# What does schedule of "0/1 * * * *" mean in kubernetes cron job

Tags: linux, unix, kubernetes, cron

A cron job whose schedule is "0/1 * * * *"  is getting executed every 2.5 minutes. But ideally if we go by the unix cron job schedule it should be every minute starting from 0 to 59. Could some one please help me understand this schedule.

Comment: see [the expression in crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0/1_*_*_*_*)

Comment: It should schedult it every minute. The fact that it does not makes me ask this questions: how do you measure this time? what is the cronjob's concurrencyPolicy set to?  and how long does the job run?

Comment: @Matt it runs for 2 or 3 seconds. I measured this time because after the pod goes into running state it stays only for 2 or 3 seconds and after that it goes to completed state and the concurrent policy is default i.e. allow concurrent jobs